# How to save string array in preference while iteration is going on

Tags: android

Is it possible to save string array in preference while iterating its values in loop? Say for example :

```
String[] arrayvalue = new String[5];

for (int i = 0; i <= number; i++) {

    Log.d(TAG, "ArrayValue" == " + arrayvalue[i]);

    String abcd = arrayvalue[i].toString();
    prefs.setData(context, abcd);
    Log.d("Prefs", "Saving in Preference");

}
```

There are actually 5 values, so while saving I will see "Log" is executed 5 times, but while retrieving I am only seeing the last 5th value in preference, why is that so ?

//Retrieving

```
String converteddata = prefs.getData(context);
Log.d("Prefs", "Retreiving from Preference : " + converteddata);
```

Save

```
public synchronized String getData(Context context) {
    Log.d(TAG, "getData");
    SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    return prefs.getString(DATA, DEFAULT_DATA);
}
```

//Retrieve

```
public synchronized void setData(Context context, String data) {
    Log.d(TAG, "setData");
    SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    prefs.edit().putString(DATA, data).commit();
}
```

Comment: Yes of course its possible. Show your code to put one item/value in preferences. What is type of data[]? Why do you let us guess?

Comment: @greenapps - Hey thanks, I just edited my code. Please have a look at it.

Comment: `setData(Context context, String data) `. In preferences key=value pairs are stored. So you should add one parameter more to setData(). Make it `setData(Context context, String key, String data)` and call accordingly like `setData(context, "arrayvalue"+i, abcd) ;`. Adapt putString to `putString(key, data)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own String representation of the array like this:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < playlists.length; i++) {
    sb.append(playlists[i]).append(",");
    //here you save the string each eteration
    prefsEditor.putString(PLAYLISTS, sb.toString());
}
```

Then when you get the String from SharedPreferences simply parse it like this:

```
String[] playlists = playlist.split(",");
```

I hope its the answer you look for.